# How do I add a custom 404 page for my Elastic Beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a php elastic beanstalk application set up and I want it to use my custom 404.html page if there is a 404 error. My proxy server is set to apache. Normally I would just define this line: ErrorDocument 404 /404.php in a .htaccess file or in the apache configs. I have tried putting the following in a apache.config in the .ebextensions directory:

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/update.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    encoding: plain
    content: |
      ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

This didn't seem to do anything. If anyone could advise please let me know.

Comment: Can you ssh into the EB instance and add it manually?. This is so that you know what needs to be done automatically. Once you can make it work manually, then can worry how to replicate this using ebextentions.

Comment: @Marcin I am able to add it manually and that succeeds. I just can't work out how to replicate this in ebextensions